# switching authentication table as per request parameter springSecurity in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am writing a program in springboot where user can access the application in two ways with a combination of username/password or a use of single unique 16 digit alphanumeric character which resides in separate table.
I am comfortable with logging the user with either combination of username / password or the use of 16 digit character at a time. But What I need is ability to switch between userbased and character based login. I've considered filter based approach but not sure how to start it can anyone point me to the right direction. 
What I desire is something like this:-

```
if(request.getParameter("userType").equals("userbased")){
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "SELECT u.username,r.role FROM user u  INNER JOIN user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id INNER JOIN role r ON ur.role_id = r.id WHERE u.username=?; ");
}
else if(request.getParameter("userType").equals("tokenNo")){
   //token based login logic with structure same as above
}
```

Comment: No that isn't what you desiree. Just add a filter for the case of the unique number instead of username/password combo, that filter should return an `AuthenticationToken` and next you need an `AuthenticationProvider` which knows what to do with it. Configure it and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not have to implement anything new. If you take a look at the documentation of the [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html), you will see this explained as:

> Iterates an Authentication request through a list of
>   AuthenticationProviders.
>
> AuthenticationProviders are usually tried in order until one provides
>   a non-null response. A non-null response indicates the provider had
>   authority to decide on the authentication request and no further
>   providers are tried.

**So you can define multiple AuthenticationProviders and configure them according to your different needs.** A typical use case is one `authManager` for real users (with username + pass), and another for applications (with token-based access). I assume you are implementing the very same requirement here, but even if this assumption is wrong the solution will still work for you.